# Finding asymptotes of a multivariable function in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function of multiple variables and I need to find, using python, values beyond which the function does not vary anymore.

Let's take an example of f(x,y)=exp(-x-y)

Here is the code :

```
import numpy as np

def func_opt(x,y):
    return np.exp(-x-y);
    
xmax = 10;
ymax = 10;
dx = 0.1;
dy = 0.1;
Nx = xmax//dx+1;
Ny = xmax//dy+1;
x = np.linspace(0, xmax, Nx);
y = np.linspace(0, ymax, Ny);
s = (len(x), len(y));
result = np.zeros(s);
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        result[i][j] = func_opt(x[i],y[j]);

print(result)
```

Is there any python function that can find x and y that verifies the following condition :

result[i][j]- result[i-1][j-1] < 1e-9?

Comment: Just so we're clear, the last sentence is basically the entire question, and everything that comes before it is just irrelevant fluff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the function `numpy.isclose`, which given a tolerance, returns a boolean indicating whether the elements passed to it are close.

I would use it together with a `np.roll` function, along the right axis.

```
np.isclose(result, np.roll(result, shift=1, axis=1), atol=1e-9)
```

This returns a matrix the size of your result matrix, with boolean values indicating whether this cell is close enough to its neighbor. When I say neighbor (shift=1, axis=1). You might be interested in axis=0, or shigt=-1, so you can try and see what you need (horizontal or vertical direction - i or j).

Do note that roll has boundary issues (the most right element, when shifter right, comes back to the beginning), so I would pad the array to be a bit bigger.